# jQuery Datepicker onSelect addClass

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Is there a way to add a class with jQuery's addClass to an anchor element for a date in datepicker?

For example, each time a date is clicked on an inline datepicker instance, I want the border to be red (this instance of datepicker is not assigned to an input element). If clicked again afterward, the color can return to transparent (or whatever the original color was.) I tried using onSelect, but there was no way to get the specific anchor for the date; so I tried

```
$('td a.ui-state-default').live( 'click', function () {})
```

when I used hasClass, addClass, and removeClass to achieve the effect I want, the element apparently had the class--but would be either reverting/overwritten or simply not link the proper style rules. Any suggestions on how to get this effect working?

Comment: You want the border of _what_ to be red?

Comment: Border of the date...like if July 11, 2011 is clicked on, I want the <td><a class="ui-state-default redBorder" href="#">11</a></td> to have that redBorder class or really any class that will set it apart visually from other dates.

Comment: `Each one that I click needs to keep the red border until it is clicked again. So if I click on the 6th, 7th, and 8th of this month--they'll all have red borders until clicked again. –  notam2774 Jul 11 '11 at 21:26` Were you able to implement this functionality or used multidatespicker? Please share your thoughts if you were successful in implementing the above mentioned functionality. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with straight CSS.

```
table.ui-datepicker-calendar a.ui-state-default.ui-state-active {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/N7wpE/

Comment: Each one that I click needs to keep the red border until it is clicked again. So if I click on the 6th, 7th, and 8th of this month--they'll all have red borders until clicked again.

Comment: @user it sounds like you want to actually be able to _select_ multiple dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539694/pick-multiple-dates-one-by-one-with-jquery-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
$('.ui-state-default').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('red')){
        $(this).removeClass('red');
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('red');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.red { border: 1px solid #f00; }
```

Comment: I did precisely this, but unfortunately it had no effect. The element still had the class, though, it didn't show up in the HTML tab of firebug and the color property didn't appear.

Comment: Or simply `function () { $(this).toggleClass('red'); }`.

Comment: @user768459: It got the class though?

Comment: Nevermind, it isn't getting the class at all. It only has the class for the duration of the click event, or for as long as the handler function is running--so effectively the class isn't being added.